# Spark UDF for keeping cumulative sum

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks, spark-structured-streaming

In Spark Structured Streaming Dataframe I have a column Diff.

Based on Diff column I wanted to create another call which maintains cumulative sum of the Diff column.

> Approach 1

So I created a UDF with below code:

```
elapsed_time = 0

def cumulative(val):
    global elapsed_time
    elapsed_time = elapsed_time + int(val)
    return elapsed_time 
    
CumSum = udf(lambda t: cumulative(t))
```

Then I am calling the udf as below:

```
#Adding Cummlative Sum Column using UDF
dataframe2 = dataframe1.withColumn("CumulativeTime", CumSum(f.col('Diff')))
```

This is working perfectly fine

**Will it cause any issues further? Since the variable elapsed_time is updated by all the worker nodes.**

> Approach 2

I tried an approach which uses Accumulator as below:

```
elapsed_time = sc.accumulator(0)

def cumulative(val):
    global elapsed_time
    elapsed_time.add(int(val))
    return elapsed_time.value
    
CumSum = udf(lambda t: cumulative(t))
```

but I received an exception  **An exception was thrown from a UDF: 'Exception: Accumulator.value cannot be accessed inside tasks**

Any alternative, workaround or suggestion would be helpful.

Comment: cumulative sum can also be done using native spark functions. do you have any specific reason to use an UDF?

Comment: can you suggest which native spark functions ? I tried using aggregating function. Aggregation functions works perfectly fine with batch one but in streaming I need to add watermark which leaves last row in the buffer

Comment: You can use pyspark.sql.functions.expr : df.withColumn('cumsum', expr('sum(Diff) over (order by XXX)'))